# How to add description to the aws security group ingress rule?

Tags: aws-cli

with below aws cli command.

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-07b70f5d9078322f2 --protocol tcp --port 5439 --cidr 175.101.107.216/32

It is creating successfully, but can't find parameter to add description, please suggest.

[image: description]

Comment: See Example 11 in the documentation https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html

Comment: that is changing the complete structure for one description. And which should be used here, 3389 or ToPort